# HANDLING ERRORS IN SQL PROCEDURES - ORACLE DATABASE

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, error-handling

How can I catch an error in a procedure and the procedure will continue running to the end without failing.

Usually a procedure fails when it encounters an error during the execution of the procedure. but there is a way that you can add a condition to the procedure to write the error somewhere and the procedure will continue to the end without aborting.

Comment: SQL Server and Oracle are different database products. Please only tag what you are actually using. If you are using Oracle then there's a [section in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-343E0653-9BCE-48F5-A00A-795D77B96B44) about exception handling. (But don't rely on `dbms_output` as their examples tend to; it might not be visible to the caller. An autonomous procedure to log to a table can be a useful alternative.)

Comment: Error handling is a large topic. For SQL Server, [read this](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) for starters.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman I am checking that out right away.

Comment: use debugging to handle error.

Comment: It is described [**in the documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-0502DC1A-F0A5-4180-A912-6A5CDC855F56) with **lots of examples**. Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `EXCEPTION` handling clause within an nested `BEGIN`/`END` block then you can continue after the nested block:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name
IS
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Do something');
    RAISE ZERO_DIVIDE;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This will be skipped');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      -- Do something to handle the execption (or, in this case, nothing)
      NULL;
  END;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Continue');
END;
/
```

*Note: Catching `OTHERS` is generally bad practice as you should catch specific, expected errors and then if there is an unexpected error it is propagated and can be debugged. If you catch all errors then you cannot tell what error occurred.*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name
IS
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Do something');
    RAISE ZERO_DIVIDE;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This will be skipped');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      -- Do something to handle the execption (or, in this case, nothing)
      NULL;
    WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
      -- Do something to handle the execption (or, in this case, nothing)
      NULL;
  END;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Continue');
END;
/
```

> [is there] a way that you can add a condition to the procedure to write the error somewhere?

Instead of using `NULL` in the `EXCEPTION` clause you can use an `INSERT` statement to write the error to a table or you can call an `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` to handle writing the error.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a5b687fc4a760501900fc28ab7864932)*